# Python grammar of with construct is not flexible enough

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Today, playing with locks, I noticed the following situation. Suppose that I have the following code that needs to be locked. Using the old way with acquire and release:

```
lock=Lock()
lock.acquire()
a=foo()
if condition:
    doSomething()
    lock.release()
else:
    lock.release()
    doSomethingElse()
```

This piece of code couldn't be implemented using the `with` construct:

```
lock=Lock()
with lock:
    a=foo()
    if condition:
        doSomething()
else:    #This is wrong grammar here.
    doSomethingElse()
```

Or could it? Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no `else` with a `with` statement; indent your `else` to the same indentation as your `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, but that would force me to hold the lock for a longer time than what I actually want to hold it. If I use the first way I can release it when I want it.

Comment: Your first example if flawed: if `condition` is `False`, you never release the lock.

Comment: @Evert, I think I need to specify that in my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what 'with' is for. It exists to guarantee that the `release` function will be called no matter what.

If you want to conditionally call `release`, then do not use `with`. Probably there is a better alternative to your code using `with` but it is impossible to know without seeing the full context.

About your new code, IMO the best alternative would be:

```
with Lock(): # no need for the lock name
    a=foo()
    # c is used just in case your condition is a complex expression with side effects
    c = condition
    if c:
        doSomething()

if not c:
    doSomethingElse()
```

Now the scope of the lock is clear. And in case you want to add `try/catch`, or another few function calls, there will be no confusion about whether the lock is held or not.

Comment: I have changed the situation slightly. It seemed fair to let you know.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the `Lock` class properly implements the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, you can use it as follows:

```
with Lock() as lock:
    a=foo()
    if condition:
        doSomething()
    else:
        doSomethingElse()
```

If, instead, you want to `dosomethingElse()` if there is no lock, this is the code:

```
if condition:
    with Lock() as lock:
        a = foo()
        doSomething()
else:
    doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: I have changed the situation slightly. It seemed fair to let you know.